# php script that run continously and concurrently with cronjob

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have 3 scripts that do some stuff.
I want to run them continously and concurrently.

Let's say for example:
First script took 30 minutes to finish.
Second - 20 mins.
Third - 5 mins.

So I need everyone of them to run immediately after it's finished.
The 3 scripts make UPDATE in a same DB, but they need to work separately.
They can run together at once, but not couple of times(my english sucks, sorry about that).
Let's explain what I mean with example:

```
firstScript.php is running
secondScript.php is running
thirdScript.php is running

firstScript.php trying to start but it still running. Wait.(till finish)
```

May be some shell script will do the job, but how?

Comment: Are all three scripts accessible by urls?  The only thing I could think of is to create one cron script that curls sequentially to them and waits for a response before proceeding to the next when run, but this is a very ugly solution.  Consider this - could these scripts be run by user traffic elsewhere in your site, using their request to make remote calls?  The nature of php as Request-to-run makes it difficult to leverage for tasks like this.

Comment: Nope.
They're not accessible by urls. I need to run them manually.

Comment: Is it an option to save state to disk?  I can think of a few approaches that would save a paging file of what is running and when ran, load the file first and determine what to do from there.

Comment: I think it'll be easier with the method bellow. Just "tell" at the end of the script that I need to execute it again. But thanks for your help and time. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a bash script that takes one argument, and have it do something like this:

```
if [ -f /tmp/$1 ]
then
    echo "Script already running"
else
    touch /tmp/$1
    php $1
    rm /tmp/$1
fi
```

Set up a cron to run this script and pass it the name of the php script you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a shell command just before the php script dies. Example :

```
while($i < 1000)
{
$i++;
}
shell_exec("bin/php.exe some_script.php");
```

If you are working on a shared hosting account this might not work do to security issues.
note the "bin/php.exe" need to be edited for your server, point to where ever your php is installed.

Comment: Hmm.. It's just freeze for few seconds with this one and doesn't run the script again.
Safe mode is off and I'm using VPS.